# Use RStudio search replace to replace linebreaks

Tags: rstudio

In the RStudio Search/Replace tool, I am trying to replace two consecutive linebreaks by one. However, I cannot get it to find line breaks with any regex I am aware of - even when I introduce them by replacing something with `\n`, searching for `[\n]+` and similar patterns does not result in any matches. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. (I am on Windows.)

Comment: This sounds weird. Have you checked the `regex` box before replacing?

Comment: I was convinced that I did and spend quite a while trying to get this to work a few days back - however, now it works when I check the box. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. We all know the situation of spenting on the upper end of a day to figure out a problem only to then have the obvious thing pointed out, being sure we already tested it, and then it works. ;-) Glad i could help.